# how to use nested ng-bind

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple question.
input:

```
<div ng-bind="Object.title"><span ng-bind="Object.name"></span></div>
```

output:

```
<div>Title</div>
```

in this example `object.title` is success binding data, but then removes children elements. how to do it right? thanks

Comment: Can only use ng-bind on element that has no children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) within the elements themselves:

```
 <div>{{Object.title}}<span>{{Object.name}}</span></div>
```

[`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) is specifically meant to replace the content of the element with the given value.

If you want to bind HTML to an element, use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). However, I'm not sure that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ArmanMukatov Like I said, you can't with `ng-bind`; replacing the content of the element is what it's supposed to do. If you are trying to bind HTML, take a look at `ng-bind-html`. If you are trying to create  structured markup in a reusable fashion, consider creating a directive.